# Hammer.js allowing clicks within a drag area

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js to create a mobile app-style side menu that slides out on the left. When the user swipes the side menu to the left it should close.

My problem is that none of the links within the menu now work. How do you enable a tap on a link to continue to work?

It seems I need to include 'prevent_default' in order to stop the page scrolling on the drag gesture.

```
    $('.sidebar').hammer({
        prevent_default: true
    }).bind('drag', function(ev) {
        if(ev.direction == 'left') {
            $('#page').removeClass('in');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
prevent_default: false
```

this will allow you pass clicks through the container.